# Finding number of transcluded ng-repeat children in an angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to find the number of children transcluded in a directive like so:

```
<div my-directive="true">
  <span ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]>{{i}}</span>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<canvas></canvas><div class="canvas-overlay"></div>',
    controller: function($element, $transclude) {
      $transclude(function(transcludeEl) {
        $element.find('.canvas-overlay').append(transcludeEl);
      });

      console.log($element.find(".canvas-overlay")[0].children);
   })
 }
});
```

The console log gets me an empty html collection when using ng-repeat but the correct child elements when I hardcode the spans.

Context: I need to set the height of the canvas based on the number of children.

I've also tried changing the controller function to a post-link function and it still fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 controller: function($element, $transclude) {
        $transclude(function(transcludeEl) {
           $element.children().eq(1).append(transcludeEl);
 });
```

I can't `.find(".canvas-overlay")` but `.children()` can.

https://jsfiddle.net/xtx1nc2k/